# PHP CodeIgniter: load page with different content

Tags: php, codeigniter

What I am trying to do is that, whenever the user clicks on a specific assignment, they will redirect to the detail page. The detail page will have different information according to what assignment they clicked on. However, I have no idea how to implement this feature.
My home function in Controller/project is as follows

```
    public function home() {
        /*if($this->input->cookie('login_status')=='0'){
            header("location: Welcome/login");
        } else{
            */
            $this->load->database();
            $this->load->model('scheduler_model');
            $this->load->view('header.php');

            $data['username'] = $this->input->cookie('username');

            $data["getnames"]=$this->scheduler_model->get_users();
            $this->load->view('home/homepage',$data);

            $data["getassignments"]=$this->scheduler_model->get_assignment();
            $data["getselectedcourses"]=$this->scheduler_model->get_select_course();
            $this->load->view('home/assignments',$data);  
        //}
    }
```

My assignment.php in view is as follows:

```
foreach($getassignments as $getassignment){
    if(in_array($getassignment->courseID,$courseArray)){
        if($getassignment->due>date("Y-m-d")){
            ?><a href="detail">
            <?php 
            $assignName='assignment'.$i;
            echo $getassignment->name,"        ",$getassignment->due;
            //$this->input->set_cookie('assignName',$getassignment->name,time()+3600);
            $assignList =array(
                $assignName=>$this->input->set_cookie($assignName,$getassignment->name,time()+3600)
            );

            ?></a>
            <?php
            echo "<br>";
            $i=$i+1;
        } 
    }
}?>
```

Comment: You should add more details about what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried so far and what is being depicted in the code you shared. People won't be able to help you unless they understand what your problem is. :)

Answer (score 1):

> What I am trying to do is that, whenever the user clicks on a specific
>   assignment, they will redirect to the detail page. The detail page
>   will have different information according to what assignment they
>   clicked on. However, I have no idea how to implement this feature. My
>   home function in Controller/project is as follows

This is how it works!

1. You will have a method in a controller that list all assignments for your example

   `function home() {
       $data["getassignments"]=$this->scheduler_model->get_assignment();
        $this->load->view('home/homepage',$data);
   }`
2. You should have a view to listing all those assignments.

   `foreach($getassignments as $getassignment){
   echo "<p><a href = 'controller/details/".$getassignment->id."'>".$getassignment->name."</p>"
   }`

   3. you should have another method inside a controller to view that selected assignment

      `function detail($id){
         $data["getassignment"]=$this->scheduler_model->get_assignment($id);
         $this->load->view('details', $data);
      }`
   4. Finally, you need a detail view to display the one you need for the selected assignment

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks that it works. I will try later and leave feedback.